# ssrs label for blank in multi-value parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, label

i have report with multi value parameter and i get values from data set. This data set is also used for other reports, so changing it is impossible. i also want this parameter to allow blank value. and i need to label this empty value (see attached file). [image]  is it possible and how? i even don't know what to do to get the appropriate result.

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement to catch the empty value. Use NULL, 0 or whatever value fits your data.

`SELECT datafield1, CASE datafield2 WHEN NULL THEN 'empty label text' ELSE datafield2 END AS 'your column' from your_table`